# graphing results of boot in R

Tags: r, plot

let's say I have the following code:

```
library(boot)
samplemean <- function(x, d) {
  return(mean(x[d]))
}
results_qsec <- boot(data=mtcars$qsec, statistic = samplemean, R=1000)
results_wt <- boot(data=mtcars$wt, statistic = samplemean, R=1000)
plot(results_qsec)
plot(results_wt)
```

for `plot(results_wt)` I get the following: [image]

can I edit what is plotted? for instance, I'd like to get rid of the graph on the right, change the title from 'Histogram of t' to 'Histogram of bananas', and have the histograms for results_qsec and results_wt on the same graph.
Can this be done? I looked at the boot doc but couldn't find anything helpful.
Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 2):

How about this? You could, of course, change the bin width, etc., to make it look more like the original.

```
wt_t <- plot(results_wt)$t
sec_t <- plot(results_qsec)$t

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(wt_t, main = "banana")
hist(sec_t, main = "apple")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

thanks, looks good.
I found another way, using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

boot_qsec <- as.data.frame(results_qsec$t)
boot_wt <- as.data.frame(results_wt$t)

ggplot() + geom_histogram(data=boot_qsec,aes(V1)) + 
      geom_histogram(data=boot_wt ,aes(V1))
```

Comment: That's essentially the exact same thing, just using ggplot instead of base. I actually almost posted a ggplot answer but assumed you wanted something that looked similar to the output you provided.